A limit involving sequences of integers
Let $(m_{j})_{j\geq 1}$ be an arbitrary sequence of positive integers. Let $(n_{j})_{j\geq 1}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers; $A>0$. Define
$$
R_{p}:=m_{1}+\ldots+m_{p},\quad S_{p}:=m_{1}n_{1}+\ldots + n_{p}m_{p}.
$$
Then, the question is: It is true that $\lim_{p}(AS_{p}-R_{p}\log(p))=+\infty$?  What I have tried: By the mean property, as $p\rightarrow \infty$, we have
$$
\frac{R_{p}}{S_{p}}=\frac{ \frac{m_{1}+\ldots+m_{p}}{p} }{\frac{m_{1}n_{1}+\ldots + n_{p}m_{p}}{p}} \approx \frac{m_{p}}{m_{p}n_{p}}=\frac{1}{n_{p}}.
$$
Since $(n_{j})_{j\geq 1}$ is strictly increasing, $n_{p}\geq p$ and then
$$
\lim_{p} \frac{R_{p}}{S_{p}}\log(p)=0.
$$
Therefore, noting $A>0$, we get
$$
\lim_{p}(AS_{p}-R_{p}\log(p))=\lim_{p}S_{p}\left(A-\frac{R_{p}}{S_{p}}\log(p)\right)=+\infty.
$$
What do you think about the above proof?
Many thanks in advance for your comments.
